# Python extension type: super() not finding method (a.k.a. attribute) in base class

Tags: python, derived-class, base-class, getattr

I am recoding PyCXX which is a C++ wrapper for Python.

The original (working) implementation for adding methods to a new style class involved creating an "extern C" handler function for each, populating a PyMethodDef table with pointers to these handlers, and placing the PyTypeObject's table->tp_methods to this table.

Instead I'm replacing the mechanism with one that overrides getattro, searches my own data to see if this attribute has a corresponding C++ method, if so packages it up into a Callable Python object and returns it, otherwise defers to PyObject_GenericGetAttr.

This technique works if I create an instance of new_style_class:

```
# new_style_class is a C++ class deriving from ExtObj_new
_new_style_class = simple.new_style_class()
_new_style_class.func_noargs()
```

However, if I attempt to derive from new style class and invoke func_noargs() from the base, like this:

```
print( '--- Derived func ---' )
class Derived(simple.new_style_class):
    def __init__( self ):
        simple.new_style_class.__init__( self )

    def derived_func( self ):
        print( 'derived_func' )
        print( vars(super()) )
        super().func_noargs() # <-- AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'func_noargs'

d = Derived()
d.derived_func()
```

... it returns **AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'func_noargs'.**

I'm wondering whether the problem comes from the fact that I am overriding getattro rather than getattr.

Is it possible that CPython, when it attempts to invoke a base attribute, looks straight to base.getattr and misses base.getattro entirely?

If so? Does that qualify as a bug?

Comment: Please show us the exact code where `func_noargs()` is declared.  If it is just an instance attribute that happens to be callable, `super()` probably won't find it.  In other words, this code *must* work if you want `super()` to work: `simple.new_style_class.func_noargs(instance)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### References

[`tp_getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattr) is deprecated, so [`tp_getattro`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattro) would be the better decision to use. But it's not the right method to use at all. Having a look at the `Objects/typeobject.c` source file of Python, you'll find the definition of the `super` type, as well as a static function `add_methods`, which defines the methods of a type. All three together illustrate, why you'll run into problems.

#### Why not to use `tp_getattro` to "define" methods

> It is usually convenient to set this field to `PyObject_GenericGetAttr()`, which implements the normal way of looking for object attributes.

So the lookup is only defined for the object and not for the type, but methods should be defined for the type.

#### How methods are defined

The function `add_methods` iterates over `tp_methods`, defines every method with `PyDescr_NewMethod` (`PyCFunction_New` for static methods) and adds it to the dictionary of the type object.

#### How `super` searches for methods

The super type defines `tp_getattro`. Now `super().func_noargs()` will trigger a lookup for `func_noargs` within the super object. This means, that `func_noargs` will be looked up in the dictionary of every relevant super type. If nothing is found, `__class__` was requested or the second parameter to `super` was not defined or `None`, the super object will call `PyObject_GenericGetAttr` on itself. So your `tp_getattro` is never called.

#### Conclusion

If you don't like your original (working) solution, you should put the functions you return in `tp_getattro` into the dictionary of the type object.